# Mat-Dialog passing value and populate to the input fields

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I was creating a mat-dialog with table and once i clicked the first row it will populate the input fields that you selected.

[image]

but i want to put only name

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-r2dch9

Comment: You can do it by `this.dialogRef.close(row.name);`

Comment: how can i populate it in the input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-wctvne?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

First, modify `this.dialogRef.close(row)` to `this.dialogRef.close(row.name)`.

**alter-dialog.component.ts**

```
this.dialogRef.close(row.name);
```

Next, modify `app.component.ts` as below.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  version = VERSION;
  value = '';                // Add this line.

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  openAlertDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent, {});

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {   // 
      this.value = result;                            // Add these lines.
    });                                               //
  }
}
```

Then add `[(ngModel)]="value"` into your `<input type="text">`

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

Comment: what if i put a reactive form? instead of a plain input?